# mapView:viewForOverlay: not getting called

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkoverlay

Hey all..... I know this is a duplicate question but I still cannot get it to work and Im sure Im missing something simple. I have set the delegate in IB and RegionDidChange gets called so I know the mapView delegate is hooked up. However I cannot display any overlay or even get the delegate method to be called. Here is the code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

self.map.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(
                                                    newLocation.coordinate, 
                                                    milesToMeters(radius),
                                                    milesToMeters(radius)
                                                    );
self.map.centerCoordinate = newLocation.coordinate;
circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate radius:50.];    

[self.map addOverlay:circle];
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];   

}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

NSLog(@"region did change");
}

- (MKOverlayView *)map:(MKMapView *)map viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {
NSLog(@"circling");

if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKCirlce class]])

{
MKCircleView *circleView = [[[MKCircleView alloc] initWithCircle:overlay] autorelease];
circleView.lineWidth = 1.0;
circleView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];

return circleView;
}
return nil;

}
```

Many thanks. Jules

Comment: Does didUpdateToLocation get called?  Are you sure self.map is not nil (make sure its IBOutlet is connected)?

Comment: Yes didUpdateLocation is called and even viewForAnnotation is called just not viewForOverlay? Its very strange/.... any thoughts? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewForOverlay` delegate method is not named right.  It should be:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map 
            viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {
```

It must be named `mapView:viewForOverlay:` (not `map:viewForOverlay:`).

You can change the internal parameter names but not the method name.

Also, inside your `viewForOverlay` method, `MKCirlce` should be `MKCircle`.

Comment: Thank you so much I was going crazy over this!!